# Maven set version and bash

Tags: bash, maven

If I do `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=14.7.1-SNAPSHOT` from the command line, it works, but if I create a bash script with

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$1;
```

and run it with the parameter `14.7.1-SNAPSHOT` it bombs with the error

```
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

Why is that?

Note that the script is in the same folder as the pom.xml.

Comment: How did you run the script, and from which directory?

Comment: I run the script with `./setversion 14.7.1-SNAPSHOT` from the same folder where the pom.xml file is

Comment: Why have you added the `;` at the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be totally wrong, but check if you have any other `mvn` in your aliases or another program in the path that is called `mvn` taking precedence.

Comment: That was it. An alias that was pointing to the latest mvn. Put the whole path in the script and it worked.